# Sunxi ARM SoC wake-up cause?

Tags: c, arm, boot, wakeup

I'd like to capture the wake-up reason using ATF (Trusted Framework A) specifically for sun50i, but applicable to many sunxi SoCs.

Since an IRQ or NMI likely wakes up the SoC, an interrupt flag would be set. I figure the following code will help identify the IRQ, but I don't where in the wake-up flow to install this code.

```
#define mmio_read_32(c)      ({unsigned int __v = (*(volatile unsigned int *)(c)); __v; })
#define GICC_BASE            0x01c82000

INFO("SGI 0:       0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x0000));
INFO("PPI 0:       0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x0040));
INFO("UART 0:      0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x0080));
INFO("TWI 0:       0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x0098));
...
INFO("DE:          0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x01fc));
INFO("CTI0:        0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x0230));
INFO("PMU0:        0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x0260));
INFO("PMU1:        0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x0264));
INFO("PMU2:        0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x0268));
INFO("PMU3:        0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x026c));
INFO("AXI_ERROR:   0x%04x\n",      mmio_read_32(GICC_BASE + 0x0270));
```

There is a register that survives a reset: "General Purpose Register can be flag register, and it will save the value all the time when the VDD_RTC is not power off", but the problem remains on how to ascertain the wake-up reason.

Ref: [Allwinner A64 user manual](http://files.pine64.org/doc/datasheet/pine64/Allwinner_A64_User_Manual_V1.0.pdf)

---

The above code comes from hints from the Allwinner A64 user manual.

[image]

Comment: You can know which interrupt was triggered by reading bits [0..9] of the [GICC_IAR](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0048/b/Programmers--Model/CPU-interface-register-descriptions/Interrupt-Acknowledge-Register--GICC-IAR?lang=en) register in your interrupt handlers. It will give you the interrupt number, i.e. 0 for `SGI_0_IRQn`,..., 156 for `AXI_ERROR_IRQn`  in the case of a `H5` for example.

Comment: By the way, I don't understand what the code above is supposed to do.

Comment: The question was updated to explain the code. A single register would be great. I'm not seeing such a useful register in the GICv2. Maybe it is present, but the 705-page A64 docs don't share its address. This chip is closer to H6 I'm afraid.

Comment: I see a footnote on the ARM website: "GIC CPU interface 0x000C GICC_IAR". I'll experiment with that.

Comment: I just pointed you to the `IAR` `GICv2` register. From my personal experience, It can be used for determining which interrupt occured on the `A64`, `H5`, `H6` and `H616`, because all four are using a `GIC400`. So the only differences would reside in the number of interrupts and their numeric identifier, not in the way you can use `IAR` to determine the interrupt which occured. What you are referencing is the interrupt vectors table, which can pointed to be setting `vbar_el3`, `vbar_el2` and `vbar_el1` to the proper values.

Comment: And it may be anywhere in memory, and not in the `GIC` register address space.

Comment: Well, you may just have followed the link I provided in my comment. Any reason why you totally ignored it? This may help me improve my future comments.

Comment: I would suggest you to read the [Bare-metal Boot Code for ARMv8-A Processors
Application Note 527](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dai0527/a/) document for information on how the the vector tables are configured - just click on the hyperlink.

Comment: Your comment was very helpful! I learned of the existence of the GICC_IAR register. Then I followed your link which explained what the register does. I next turned to the A64 user manual and failed to find such a register address. Hunting for "GICC_IAR" on the ARM site I found "GICC_IAR can be accessed through the memory-mapped interfaces: GIC CPU interface + 0x000C = GICC_IAR". That was my last reply. (up until now I was trawling through the ATF source code trying to solve this, you see).

Comment: You will not find any information on the GIC registers in any of the Allwinner reference manuals, because there was no need to. You always will have to refer to the ARM documentation for the `GICv2` and the `GIC400`. The important information in the `A64` reference manual is at section 3.12.3.1 Interrupt Sources.", because the values provided here will be those you will have to use when programming the `GIC`.

Comment: Here are the two only documents you will need, the [CoreLink GIC-400 Generic Interrupt Controller Technical Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0471/b/) and the [ARM Generic Interrupt Controller Architecture version 2.0 - Architecture Specification](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0048/latest/)

Comment: If you were planning to use it, please note that the Architectural Timer is [broken](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/cover/904606/)  on the `A64`, and that you will get [Spurious Interrupts](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0048/b/Introduction/Terminology/Spurious-interrupts?lang=en)  from time to time, from what I have seen on my `nanopi2-a64`.